# Avoid Number() for scientific notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to do the below

`Number("0.00000000000122")` results in `1.22e-12`

But what I need to just that number to get converted from `String` to `Number`.

```js
console.log(Number("0.00000000000122"))
```

Comment: this notation is only a representation of the number that you want to see, don't worry about that, even if you type the digits 0.00000000000122 in console you will get the 1.22e-12

Comment: Btw, it's generally recommended not to use the `Number()` constructor unless you have a good reason. We can use the "unary `+` operator" and the `parseInt` global function to convert strings to primitive numbers rather than to Number objects.

Comment: @Cat `parseInt()` is for integers; in this case it would not work. Also, both `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` have the drawback (in some cases) that they accept input like "123hello" and return the number `123` without error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
console.log(Number("0.00000000000122").toFixed(20).replace(/\.?0+$/,""));
```

Explanation:

`toFixed()` will keep the number, and `replace()` will remove trailing zeroes

Edit:

It seems that you want the result of Number("0.00000000000122") to BOTH be a number and also keep it string as "0.00000000000122", not its scientific display.
In that case, you can save it as a number-type variable in ts file, then display it as a string in HTML

Comment: Then it will remove the final zero when casted into Number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with precise numbers you have to work with integers.

A Number is not an integer type, it's a float so numbers are represented in memory as a float. The toString method of the number just prints out the value in memory. The integer bit and the dot location.

```js
const scale = 18n;
const digits = 10n ** scale;

const POUND = (number) => BigInt(number) * digits;
const toPound = (number, fraction = false) => {
  if (!fraction) {
    return String(number / digits);
  }
  const str = String(number);
  if (scale < 1n) {
    return str;
  }
  return `${str.substring(0, Number(BigInt(str.length) - scale))}.${str.substr(-Number(scale))}`;
};

const a = POUND(11000);
const b = POUND(20000);

console.log('scale', String(scale));
console.log('a', toPound(a));
console.log('b', toPound(b));
console.log('mul', toPound((a * b) / digits));
console.log('add', toPound(a + b));
console.log('div', toPound(b / (a / digits), true));
console.log('sub', toPound(b - a));
```